# Magento 1.9 Error when add associated products to a configuration product in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I've been working with Magento 1.9 for a while and to create a configurable product is not any problems to me, but I just encountered an weird issue with adding **associated products** to a **configurable product** on one of my Magento site.

When I fill out simple product (Associated product) info and click on Create, nothing happens but only a javascript box that is keep loading.

[image]

Any one have experienced similar issues and any fixes to this?

Comment: you can check in console any error when create simple products

Comment: @RakeshDonga I found the error by using console... Thanks :). I actually also looked at the console earlier, but I didn't know why I missed an error message.